# How to choose image/video from treelist in SXA?

Tags: sxa

Is there a way to make a **datasource template** that will have a treelist where you can choose the **image or video** (it can be two seperate **treelists**) and the display those images or videos in the code (.cshtml file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer from Sumit you can have a TreeList in the template that has its source in the media folder so you can select images or videos.

To fetch this data you can use Scriban. Take a look at https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/102/sitecore-experience-accelerator/the-embedded-functions-for-the-scriban-template.html for the available extensions. You will need `sc_followmany` to loop through the selected items (images) from the TreeList. And for each of those (media)items you can use `sc_medialink` to get the media url. This will be something like:

```
{{ for i_image in (sc_followmany i_datasource "Images") }}
  <img src="{{ sc_medialink i_image }}"/>
{{ end }}
```

ps: didn't test the Scriban code, just combined some examples here - so it might be slightly different but it should give you an idea

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `TreeList` field and point the source in the template where your image or video exists in the Sitecore Tree.

And to read the items from Treelist, you can use this link and find all the details to read the value in code.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/access-checklist,-multilist,-treelist,-and-treelistex-fields.html

I think this will give you all the details of an Image and Video item.